# How to extend custom date range selection in bootstrape daterangepicker

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am using bootstrap daterangepicker plugin, I am facing problem by selecting large range like 3-4 years in custom range. currently it allows custom range within one month only. I tried the `minDate` and `maxDate` from other [plugin](https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Date-Range-Picker-Plugin-jQuery.html) which is also not working here.

And how can I search all time data by clicking all time tab and search it within  `minDate` and `maxDate` range.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5gh61se4/)**

```
 $('.selectrange').daterangepicker({
    showDropdowns: true,
    timePicker: true,
    minDate: [moment().subtract(20,'years'),'inclusive'],
    maxDate: [moment(),'inclusive'],
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'All Time':'all-time', // [minDate, maxDate]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick for you:

Add option `linkedCalendars: false`, for example:

**Code:**

```
$('.selectrange').daterangepicker({
    linkedCalendars: false,
    showDropdowns: true,
    timePicker: true,
    minDate: moment().subtract(20, 'years'),
    maxDate: moment(),
    ranges: {
        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
        'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
        'All Time': 'all-time', // [minDate, maxDate]
    }
});
```

**Screenshot:**

[image: Date Range Picker]

Comment: And one more thing I forgot to ask, how to prevent `endDate` crossing current date(today). like you can see in the calender 2035, It should not be greater than current date & time.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want this right.

```
'All Time':[moment().subtract(20,'years'), moment()]
```

Comment: And what about the extension of custom date range selection, which is the main problem mentioned in the question.

Comment: As you can see in these [examples](https://sensortower.github.io/daterangepicker/).

Comment: Which extension ?

Comment: I am facing problem by selecting large range like 3-4 years in custom range. currently it allows custom range within one month only. tried the minDate and maxDate from other plugin which is also not working.

Comment: Incomplete answer